# Cant access specific page in wp-admin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, call

I have moved a website from one hosting server to another, webpage works with no problem but when i access wp-admin / edit page a receive an error.

I have already tried to add some code in comments but then another error appears. All errors coming are in same mode, cant find function or file.

- class 'WP_Privacy_Policy_Content' not found in /var/www/vhosts/perisweb.gr/lg-insurance.gr/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286, referer: https://www.xxx.gr/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page
- PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_reset_vars() in /var/www/vhosts/perisweb.gr/lg-insurance.gr/wp-admin/themes.php on line 133, referer: https://www.xxx.gr/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-upload wp-includes and wp-admin folders and try again or you can upload fresh wp-includes and wp-admin folders.